# Floated element not clearing to a new line in document's flow

Tags: css, css-float

I am attempting to learn how to use floats and have created a test page with 3 floated paragraph elements.

All 3 paragraph elements have been floated `left`, so that they are essentially in-line and form 3 columns. The second of these elements has a `clear: right` property. I expected this to force the third floated paragraph element onto a 'new line' (so to speak) in the document's flow, i.e. so that it is below the first two floated paragraphs, but this is not the case. Could anyone explain why this is?

Code below:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#float1 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#float2 {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#float3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<p id="float1"> Float 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <p id="float2"> Float 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <p id="float3"> Float 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

I'm certain that this is a misunderstanding on my part. My apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: right is to clear right, left to clear left ... actually your third p is on a new line because there is clear:left on it that cleared the previous left floated element

Comment: by doing your last edit I think you understand and see the difference ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hey Temani thanks for pointing out my error. But I still can't see why after using clear:right on the second floating element why the third still appears on the same "line". Wouldn't clear:right make the third element drop down?

Comment: no, clear:right will clrea float:right and you are using float:left .. so you need clear:left to clear float:left :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah ok, so you can't use clear:right, with float:left?

Comment: yes ;) simply play with different values and you will get it .. check this link https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/